# Object Property named with ? not working inside map in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-maps

I am new to Angular, the `job.job_company_companyName`, `the job.job_company.location` and the `job.jobTitle`, both of them work/can be searched on based on the filter: But when I added the object of Jobs with question mark (?) for example: `job.job_details?.jobCountry` and `job.job_details?.jobCity?` they are not being filtered, the 3 upper lines are being filtered except the two lines below.

What do you think I should do to make this thing work?
What to change?
Why is the property with the question mark not working properly?

here's my **search.component.ts**

```
this.filteredList$ = combineLatest(this.list$, this.filter$).pipe(
  map(([jobs, filterString]) =>jobs.filter(job => 
    job.job_company.companyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
    job.jobTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
    job.job_company.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
    job.job_details?.jobCountry.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
    job.job_details?.jobCity?.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
    )),
  tap(filtered => {
    this.allJobs = filtered;
    return this.jobsChunk = filtered.slice(0, 9)
  })
);
```

Heres **jobs.model.ts**

```
export interface Jobs {
  jobsId: string;
  jobTitle: string;
  job_details?: JobDetails;
  job_package: JobPackage;
  job_status: JobStatus;
  job_company: CompanyProfile;
  createdDate?: string;
}

export interface JobDetails {
  jobCity?: string;
  jobCountry: string;
  jobType: string;
  jobCategory: string;
  jobTags: string[];
  jobDescription: string;
}

export interface CompanyProfile {
  companyName: string;
  location: string; 
}
```

Comment: Can you describe exactly what is not working? And also it would be good to know the data on which you are executing this map function.

Comment: Hello Simon, Thank you for your reply. I edited the content and what's not working is that its filtering doesn't work when I added the line job_details? which obviously have a question mark ? I wanna know why the filtering doesn't work when I added the two lines and the filter is not also working with the property with question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the condition implementations, in that case:

```
job.job_details?.jobCity?.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1
```

If `job_details` or `jobCity` are undefined, the comparation will be `undefined !== -1`, and it will be `true`.

A simple approach will be to use the `> -1` instead of `!== -1` condition.

Or check the property before:

```
job.job_details?.jobCity && job.job_details.jobCity.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase()) !== -1
```

Comment: Hi, there! Thank You Cristian for your feedback. I fixed this problem of mine by just using `job.job_details?.jobCountry` only.. both the city and the country can be searched through this.. there is no any extension like `job.job_details?.jobCountry.indexOf(filterString.toLowerCase())...` it just works by using this one `job.job_details?.jobCountry`

Comment: But man that worked! Oh thank you so much! I tried it also with the country.